# Java ZK ListBox listModel out of sync after sorting

Tags: java, listbox, zk

hey guys i am new to ZK framework i have a listbox being sorted in the view later i pass the listBox to the controller and i need the items being selected by the user but in the model the items are syncronized with the sorting but in the getSelection array is not syncronized with the sort insted with the original data here is the code.

```
public void createPDFFromModel(Listbox list,String ref){                
    BindingListModelList model = (BindingListModelList)list.getModel();
    for(int i=0;i<model.size();i++){
        System.out.println((((ZamoraListitemAdapter)model.get(i)).getName()));
    }  
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
    //Data Printed OK.
    java.util.ArrayList<ZamoraListitemAdapter>selections = new java.util.ArrayList<ZamoraListitemAdapter>(model.getSelection());
    for(int i=0;i<selections.size();i++){
        ZamoraListitemAdapter clazz = (ZamoraListitemAdapter)selections.get(i);
        System.out.println(clazz.getName());
        //Out of sync with model and with sorting 
    }
```

my question is how i get the order of the items after the sort in getSelection model. i am using ZK 5.2.8

Answer (score 0):

You could [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) `selections` after you create it.
There are maybe other/better solutions, but you have
to write what you try to achieveif you need more help.

### Reply to Comment

What I mean is

```
ArrayList<ZamoraListitemAdapter>selections = 
new ArrayList<ZamoraListitemAdapter>(model.getSelection());
Collections.sort(selections);
```

So `selections` is a `List` of all your selected items and as long
as you compare the items the same way, they should be in the right order

#### In case you mean reorder and not sorting...

For me sorting means it is automatic and done by a algorithm.
Reordering instead means you, for example, drag the objects around.

If you mean reordering, and your `Model` hasn't a way to know if
a item is selected, you probably did something wrong.
Cos zk has got the two classes [`ListModelList`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/ListModelList.html) and [`AbstractListModel`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/AbstractListModel.html)
wich implement all methods needed for selection behavior and a custom
`Model` should, if the programmer wants a selectable `Model`, inherent
from one of them, cos it's the easiest way.

You should may also read [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/Performance%20Tips/Listbox,%20Grid%20and%20Tree%20for%20Huge%20Data/Implement%20ListModel%20and%20TreeModel).

Comment: yes but the getModel in this case have a inner array which is getSelection the getModel array is being syncronized with the View but the subArray not and there is not method isSelected :(

Answer (score 0):

```
model.getSelection()
```

returns a Set (no order), instead use

```
model.getInnerList()
```

that returns ListModeList